# Using Regex and PowerShell, I am trying to retrieve users Full name from the DistinguishedName attribute in ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use Regex to retrieve the full name of the user. So if I return the DistinguishedName of a user, I want the string between "CN=" and the first ",". For example if I use the ActiveDirectory Powershell module:

```
$disName = (get-aduser -identity mySamAccountName -Properties Distinguishedname).Distinguishedname
```

the output would be

```
CN=MyFirstname MyLastname,OU=Parent,OU=Child,DC=DomainControler,DC=com
```

I want the string "MyFirstname MyLastname" using regex. I found a horrible solution to even look at it hurts my eyes but I know regex is better I just cant figure out how to use it to target the string between CN= and ,

```
# My Solution. Hard on the eyes :-(
$fullname = $dishName.substring($dishName.IndexOf("=") + 1, $dishName.IndexOf(",") - 3).trim()
```

Please help me with regex as an effective tool...

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/5sPX8G/1 or https://regex101.com/r/5sPX8G/2

Comment: Wow the lookbehind was really confusing me. I have to study that more. Thank you for the solution I will try to use this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`cn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-cn) attribute ("Common Name"):

```
$disName = (Get-ADUser -Identity mySamAccountName -Properties cn).cn
```